# Grid nesting in CSS-frameworks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks, cascade-framework

I don't understand grid nesting in (any of) CSS frameworks.

I'm using [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) CSS framework with 24 colum grid — one column = 4.16667%, two — 8.33333%, twelve — 50%, etc.

This is my grid for 1920 pixel browser width — left part = 10 columns (41.66667%), right part = 14 columns (58.33333%) — [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymgsH?editors=110).

Inside the right part there is a heading and a content block:[image]

Heading has 1 column padding (in Foundation it is called «push»):

```
<div class="row small-padding-horizontal-1 medium-padding-horizontal-1 large-padding-horizontal-1 xlarge-padding-horizontal-1 xxlarge-padding-horizontal-1">…</div>
```

— as you see on the attached image heading does not fit the grid.

Content block is 5 columns wide:

```
<div class="small-5 medium-5 large-5 xlarge-5 xxlarge-5">…</div>
```

— as you see on the attached image this block does not fit the grid — it is not 5 columns wide.

And this is absolutely right and obvious — right block is 58.33333% wide, so all inner blocks' width percents will calculate accordingly this block width, not whole window width.

My question is — how do I fit the grid for my nested blocks which are inside parent blocks?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymgsH?editors=110)

Comment: Would you mind linking to a fiddle?

Comment: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymgsH?editors=110) — there you can see 1920px grid.

Comment: what do you want to fit? 5 column grid in 14-column ?

Comment: Yes, I want to 5 column block be real 5 column inside the right 14 column block — look at the screenshot and compare with the gray 24 column grid — 5 column block does not look 5 column.

Comment: That's not how grid frameworks work. They're always going to get their width from the width of their containing element.

Answer (score 1):

Responsive frameworks work with % width of parent divs..

Calculating according to your needs is a little bit trickier and messy at times.

If you look at your requirement you want to fit `5 column` in a `14-column` grid.

to achieve this you should do a calculation like this.

Your `14-column` is now `24-column` while nesting so `5-columns in 14-columns` occupying a space of `35.174%`.Considering `24 columns` that would be `8.57 columns` which is not a whole number so choose the one that is closest to it ( 8 or 9 columns).

But if you want to exactly have `5 in 14 columns` i.e `60/7` in `24 columns` you should have that as a whole number giving you .. `14*7 columns` `10*7 colums` and `5*7columns`

Your grid should be `178-column` with `70-columns` to left and `98-columns` to the right
and `35-columns` inside of `98-columns` grid.

easier way write custom class for the 5 columns grid to occupy the `35.17%`

Comment: @artuska LCM of all the grid values..:P

Answer (score 0):

Well, CSS frameworks provide a grid only for the first level blocks — all nested blocks should be manually calculated to fit top level grid.

This is calculations for the red block to fit the main grid (right container also changes column count depending of screen resolution):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) { width: (5 / 14 * 100 + 0%); } /* width — 5 columns, parent container — 14 columns -> 35.7% */
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) { width: (7 / 18 * 100 + 0%); } /* width — 7 columns, parent container — 18 columns -> 38.88 */
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) { width: (7 / 18 * 100 + 0%); } /* width — 7 columns, parent container — 18 columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { width: (10 / 22 * 100 + 0%); } /* width — 10 columns, parent container — 22 columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { width: (16 / 24 * 100 + 0%); } /* width — 16 columns, parent container — 24 columns */
```

So, I'm no more using column classes in HTML and Foundation framework's grid.css file because it is totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

Things work differently for every framework.

In Cascade Framework, a grid element basically just needs the `col` class, and you can infinitely nest `col` classes.

To easily allow for infinite nesting, grid elements have neither padding nor margin. For a consistent gutter across your page, you typically complement the `col` class with the the `cell` class as a wrapper for your content.

Example :

```
<div class="col width-1of2">
    <div class="col width-1of2">
        <div class="cell">
            [Content]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col width-fill">
        <div class="col width-1of3">
            <div class="cell">
                [Content]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col width-1of3">
            <div class="col width-3of5">
                <div class="cell">
                    [Content]
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col width-fill">
                <div class="cell">
                    [Content]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col width-fill">
            <div class="cell">
                [Content]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col width-fill">
    <div class="col width-1of4">
        <div class="cell">
            [Content]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col width-fill">
        <div class="col width-2of3">
            <div class="cell">
                [Content]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col width-fill">
            <div class="cell">
                [Content]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this demo**](http://jslegers.github.io/responsiveness/) and the [**official documentation**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/grid-presentational.html).